# Create a rule to enforce defaults on an Parameter attribute

Tags: c#, parameters, attributes, default

I'm looking at the CallerMemberName Attribute.  When you specify a method like this

```
public void TraceInfo(string propertyName, [CallerMemberName] string memberName)
```

We get a compile time error stating that

> Parameter with caller info must have a default value

The CallerMemberName Attribute is sealed, I would like to enforce having a default parameter like this class does

**How can I enforce the same policy for having defaults on a regular attribute class?**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class DefaultEnforcedAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DefaultEnforcedAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: @DownVoter, can you explain the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those verifications are done at compile-time, thus, they should be implemented by the compiler.

The good news is since the inception of compiler platform *Roslyn*, you can implement *visitors* so you can extend C# compiler with your custom verifications.

I would start reading these other Q&As to see a sample of checking things using Roslyn:

- [How to check if a property is decorated with a custom attribute using Roslyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601687/how-to-check-if-a-property-is-decorated-with-a-custom-attribute-using-roslyn)
- [How to get all properties that are anotated with some attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594847/how-to-get-all-properties-that-are-anotated-with-some-attribute)

Also, you should read Roslyn's official docs, specially this article: [Getting Started C# Syntax Analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis). Also see [C# and Visual Basic - Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer for Your API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx)

Finally, you might want to download and install [.NET Compiler Platform SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK).

### Approach #2 for those who don't like having to install a Visual Studio Extension across many machines

Another old-school approach which would be integrated as part of the project build it can be an MSBuild target calling a MSBuild task implemented in C# which could load the assembly that has been built using the `AfterTargets` attribute on `<Target>` with the value `"AfterBuild"`. It would look as follows:

```
<Target Name="EnforcePostCompilationRules" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
     <EnforceMethodParameterDefaultValue />
</Target>
```

That task would load the whole assembly and using reflection it would look for all types with methods having parameters using some attribute. If some parameter has an attribute to enforce default parameter values but the parameter *has no default value*, you throw a build error with a meaningful message pointing out which method failed the whole validation.

### Approach #3: Install the Roslyn extension using NuGet

Perhaps you got excited about the wider possibilities that Roslyn brings to you. Check this Q&A on which someone has answered that installing Visual Studio extensions is possible wrapping it as a *NuGet package*:

- [NuGet Package which installs a VSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119829/nuget-package-which-installs-a-vsix)

Comment: How can you install this Compiler modification to visual studio?  So you're saying that CallerMemberName has custom Code so that it only works for that attribute?

Comment: @johnny5 I've not checked this, but that attribute validation should be part of official C# compiler distribution, that's all.

Comment: Thanks I'll do some more investigating and hopefully I'll find out

Comment: @johnny5 The problem is that you can expect an answer on which you could see a full sample code on how to do what you want, but you can be 100% sure that a Roslyn extension is your solution. It shouldn't be that hard. I imagine a visitor on which you visit all method parameters from the project being compiled, and if any of those parameters has a given attribute, you check it has a default value, and it it doesn't have one you throw a compilation error.

Comment: I Agree, your answer is the solution. 1. I want to investigate to see how to do it that way.  2. If there is another way with out extending the comipler, because that won't carry across to other machines.

Comment: @johnny5 You're welcome. Well, you've the other answer which does that check during run-time... But I feel that this isn't the right way of doing it. There's an alternate approach I can add in my answer... hold a minute :)

Comment: @johnny5 Done ;) The second approach can be distributed as part of the project source code, since it's just an assembly containing a custom MSBuild task.

Comment: @johnny5 Does the second approach fit better in your scenario?

Comment: preferable I'd like a way to do it in code, but the second example, will allow it to be distributed appropriately so that fits my approach thank you

Comment: @johnny5 Ok! You're welcome. Hold a minute more, I'll re-update the answer and maybe you end up trying the Roslyn approach :D

Comment: @johnny5 Re-updated! Check it out. Probably you won't go for that approach, but you and even other readers might be interested on just knowing that installing a VSIX using NuGet is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter attributed with `[CallerMemberName]` must be optional. This allows you to omit this parameter when calling the method. C# will then automatically fill this parameter with the caller member name.

```
public void TraceInfo(string propertyName, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
```

You cannot enforce this rule at compile time since this would involve some compiler magic, but you can do it in the attribute's code (e.g. in the static constructor) with some reflection. You would have to enumerate the types and their methods.

Somethings like this:

```
var faultyProps = assembly.GetTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
    .SelectMany(m => m.GetParameters())
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DefaultEnforcedAttribute>() != null && !p.IsOptional);
```

Comment: I'm well aware of that... My Question is How can I enforce this on a regular attribute?

Comment: Are you saying the the CallerMemberName attribute is special and this has custom roslyn to generate the compile time warning?

Comment: See my answer, I believe that your answer is outdated. It would be fine before Roslyn. Well, before Roslyn, there were things like Code Contracts which did the code analysis against the IL...

Comment: Adding analysers to VS would mean that this check would not be made on other installations of VS not having this extension; however, throwing an exception would be tied to this attribute and always work.

Comment: But the OP asked how `[CallerMemberName]` does it, and it's not done during run-time but compile-time. About the thing of not having the analyzer on any VS installation, I believe that if I were the OP I wouldn't worry about this because it's a particular requirement that the OP has on his/her projects...

Comment: Hmmm I believe that you should edit your question and drop the part of *compiler magic* and *you can't enforce this rule at compile time*, you know that since Roslyn, there's no magic, it's regular C# code checking C# compilation :D

Comment: Yes, but it's code running in a VS extension, not in code of the project itself. I think that both solutions don't exclude each other.

Comment: I don't doubt it, I'm not saying that your answer isn't valid. Basically your answer won't address OP concern about how `[CallerMemberName]` does the whole checking during compile-time. That's all.